# Configure Logic App with Managed Identity

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics, azure-managed-identity, azure-service-principal, azure-managed-app

I am new to the Azure services and seek help with the Managed Identities.
My task is to create a managed connection between my Logic App and my Log Analytics Workspace. I have created a system assigned identity and have the respective object ID. When I use the Azure Logs Monitor action in my logic app, it asks if I should connect by signing in or service principal.
[Image for Azure Log Analytics Action fields when service principal option is selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjlpw.png)

What should be the next step, should I add the Object ID of my logic app in the log analytics workspace, then what about the fields in the above image link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service Principal doesn't have any roles in the scenario above. The image asks for an **app's client ID, Tenant ID and secret**. All we need to do is **create an app in the app registration**, **create a secret in it** and get these three parameters from there. **Add this app as a contributor or desired role as per need in the workspace** (in my case which is Log Analytics workspace), **add the three parameters into the Logic App action** as seen in above image and we are good to go. The Logic app would run on the managed connection now.